# How do I create a blob object (.PDF) in Angular from IHttpActionResult data?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, blob

I am using blob to view the PDF file from API(ASP.NET webAPI 2) and all are working fine with `Angular 5`.

But recently we move from Angular 5 to version 7 and I am start getting error while viewing PDF file.

please check the attached error's screenshot

[image]

Below are our implementation

**Controller.cs**

```
[HttpGet, Route("download")]
public IHttpActionResult DownloadReport(int ID) {
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var model = _report.GetPdfByte(ID);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(model.PDF) {
        Position = 0
    };
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = model.PDF.Length;
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = model.Name };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
    return Ok(result);

}
```

**service.ts**

```
GetFile(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.hostName + url 
         ,{responseType: "blob"}
    );
}
```

**component.ts**

```
getReport(id:number) {
    this._db.GetFile('api/reports/download?id='+id).subscribe(d=>this.downloadReport(d));
}

//Blob-binary large object that stores a binary data..
// URl- it will generate custom url to read the Pdf file
downloadReport(data: any) {
    let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    let url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
}
```

Please help me to solve or debug the error.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the size of downloaded file? does it match the expected size of your pdf?

Comment: @AlexandrMihalciuc I have updated my question please check.